# C++ find_if with predicate isalpha gives error

Tags: c++, std

I can't understand why I have this error, apparently the isalpha function is redeclared twice (my editor marks me: "2 more overloads") but I don't understand why, this is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cin.tie(nullptr);ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    string line;
    string::iterator prev, act;
    while(cin>>line){
        // act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](int x) {return isalpha(x);}); // GOOD
        act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isalpha); // ERROR
        cout<<*act<<endl; 
    }
}
```

I use g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Error:

```
1215.cpp: In function 'int main()':
1215.cpp:14:56: error: no matching function for call to 'find_if(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
         act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isalpha); // ERROR
                                                        ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from 1215.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:3808:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Predicate> _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
     find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:3808:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
1215.cpp:14:56: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Predicate'
         act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isalpha); // ERROR
```

Note: if I don't use the "using namespace std" the code compiles and executes correctly.

Thanks in advance for any answers or advice

Comment: Well the compiler probably did you a favor since using `using namespace std` is very bad practice

Comment: There are indeed multiple overloads of `isalpha()`, and your `using namespace std` is pulling them into the local namespace, so you would have to clarify to the compiler which overload you want to use for the predicate. Better to use a lambda instead that calls `isalpha()` with the desired parameters (as your commented code shows), let overload resolution do its job. And [get rid of the `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/) statement.

Comment: According to cppreference you shouldn't use isalpha by itself anyway https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: Also, never put more than one statement in one line, this is considered bad practice and makes the code harder to read

Comment: I tried compiling the same code you posted using MSVC and it compiled and worked just fine. Perhaps it's a problem with g++?

Comment: @Shidouuu It's a problem with the program. Compiling in one compiler doesn't mean that the program is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is what might be happening.

There's an `isalpha()` in the `<cctype>` [header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) under the `std` namespace and another `isalpha()` in the `<locale>` [header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha) under the *very same* `std` namespace. `using namespace std` pulls both into the your scope and thus the ambiguity while deducing the template.

Moral of the story: Avoid *using* `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand why I have this error, apparently the isalpha function is redeclared twice (my editor marks me: "2 more overloads") but I don't understand why

Two overloads are declared, because the standard says that there are two overloads.

A good solution is to use a lambda, as you did in the comment. Unlike creating a function pointer, calling the function in the lambda allows the call to be resolved to the correct overload based on the passed arguments.

Your lambda should be improved though: Change the type of the parameter to `unsigned char`. This is needed because `char` may be a signed type, and if the value of a char is negative, then it will have a value outside the range of `unsigned char`, and passing a value outside the range of `unsigned char` into `islpha` will result in undefined behaviour. Fixed example:

```
auto isalpha = [](unsigned char c){
    return std::isalpha(c);
};
act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isalpha);
```

Also, remove the line `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @ Zoso's answer:

- Inside `<iostream>` are included `<cctype>` and `locale_facets.h` both define different `std::isalpha` functions .
- Also, inside `<cctype>` includes `<ctype.h>` (which is in fact explicitly included in the example) and `<ctype.h>` defines an `isalpha` function (without the `std` namespace).

So one way to solve the problem is to call the `isalpha` function of`<ctype.h>`, for this it is necessary to exit the current namespace (std) with `::` operator.

This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cin.tie(nullptr);ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    string line;
    string::iterator prev, act;
    while(cin>>line){
        act = find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isalpha);
        cout<<*act<<endl; 
    }
}
```